# Can some one explain why the answer to part a describes a circle, or part of it?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> The transformation $T$ from the complex $z$-plane to the complex $w$-plane is given by $w=\frac{z+1}{z+i}, z\neq i$.
>
> a) Show that $T$ maps points on the half-line $\arg z = \frac{\pi}{4}$ in the $z$-plane into points on the circle $\|w\| = 1$ in the $w$-plane.

The given solution is:

> **Answer:**
>
> a) If $z=x+iy$, the $\arg z = \frac{\pi}{4} \implies \frac{y}{x} = 1$.  Let $x=y=\lambda$.  Then:
>   \begin{align}
> w &= \frac{\lambda + \lambda i + 1}{\lambda + \lambda i + i} = \frac{(\lambda+1)+\lambda i)}{\lambda + (\lambda+1) i}\\
> \|w\| &= \left\|\frac{(\lambda+1)+\lambda i)}{\lambda + (\lambda+1) i}\right\|=\frac{\left\|(\lambda+1)+\lambda i)\right\|}{\left\|\lambda + (\lambda+1) i\right\|}\\
> &= \frac{((\lambda + 1)^2 + \lambda^2)^{1/2}}{(\lambda^2 + (\lambda + 1)^2)^{1/2}} = 1
> \end{align}
>
> Hence, the points on $\arg z = \frac{\pi}{4}$ map, under $T$, onto points on the circle $\|w\| = 1$.

I cannot understand how the answer links to the question; why does doing that manipulation answer the question?

Original image source: [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVbn.jpg), [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7rxH.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, since mod(W) = 1 describes a circle, and we have an expression for mod(w) we can equate them and say that the expression that was derived describes the equation of a circle even though it looks like it doesn't. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

we can show that the image of the line $arg \, z = \pi/4$ is the unit circle $|w| = 1.$

we will use two facts about fractional linear transformation:

(a) circles transforms  to circles,

(b) the point and the image on a circle transform to point and its image on the transformed circle.

the points $-1$ and $-i $ are reflections on the (line)circle $arg \, z = \pi/4,$  therefore their transformation $0$ and $\infty$ are images on the transformed circle. that is the image of the line is the circle with center at $0.$

to find the radius of this circle we use the fact that $0$ is mapped to $-i$ which is unit distance from $0.$  the claim follows.